# Microsoft Office 2003 won't work on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office

My parents (in another country, so I can't get at their computer) have installed Microsoft Office on their Windows 8 machine. When they try to run it, they get this message:

```
The temp folder is on a drive that is full or is inaccessible. 
Free up space on the drive or verify that you have permission on the Temp Folder.
```

Googling suggests that this might be something to do with the UAC. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the problem is, BUT..a few questions for someone else that might be able to help you, do does the pc in question have `internet access`? is the pc in question low on `HARD DISK` space?

Comment: Have they tried disabling UAC to see what effect that has on the problem?

Comment: support ends for Office 2003 in April 2014, so stop wasting your time to install it.

Comment: @magicandre1981: that's fair enough, but the fact is that my parents are pretty old, and have used Office 2003 for years. They tried Office 2007, but just couldn't get used to the new ways of doing things. So they'll want to stick with 2003.

Comment: @Sickest: It does have internet access, and I don't believe it's low on hard-disk space, although it's hard for me to be sure (since I can't get near it!)

Comment: i would high recommend you tell them to download team viewer or logmein to be able to remotely access the computer as Louis suggested.

Comment: install them LibreOffice, which is free, get a lot of updates and looks like Office 2003: https://www.libreoffice.org/default/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a free tool like TeamViewer to get access to their machine. They only need to run it and give you a few numbers before you get remote access to their machine.

Once you've done this you can disable UAC in the control panel (to eliminate it as a cause) and try re-installing. This will also give you access to check the event viewer for any related errors.

Comment: Yup. I think that's got to be the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 First I would use the disk clean up wizard delete everything
 delete all from  c:\windows\temp
 delete all from  C:\Users\<username here>\appdata\local\Temp 
 Empty Trash

 As suggested by @Sickest the hard drive probably full or near full.
 Now go through and delete other unnecessary files.
```